# How would I check if browser is using Javascript?

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to write a method to see if the user has Javascript enabled in my custom browser app I'm making, if so then on my browser settings DialogFragment have the switch update onCreate to disabled or enabled, depending if Javascript is enabled or disabled for my webview.

I would assume I would use getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled(); on webview in the method, but found no more documentation on it. How would I go about writing a method to check this?

Comment: If there is such a method, have you tried if it does what you think?

Answer (score 0):

you can only programatically change if your WebView´s javascript is enabled or disabled, so you are supossing to know the status.

```
private static boolean jsEnabled; 

//enable javascript
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
jsEnabled = true;

//disable javascript    
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
jsEnabled = false;
```

use the boolean variable `jsEnabled` to know the status of your webview´s javascript

or use the method **[getJavaScriptEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getJavaScriptEnabled%28%29)**

> **getJavaScriptEnabled()**: Returns true if JavaScript is enabled